# How to make one flask app as an external client for a second flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have the following scenario:

I am making an app and ask the user if he wants to either upload his own CSV file or not. If the user says yes, then he will be able to upload a CSV and the data is stored in a DB, and if he says no, he will have options of using some default data.

What I want to do is to separate both these cases into two different flask applications, say: `app-yes` (when the user says yes to uploading a CSV) and `app-no` (when the user doesn't want to upload a CSV).

I would like to know if it is possible to use and call the `app-yes` as a kind of a third party client and as a separate route in the `app-no` application?

Assume a folder `Desktop/FolderA` with the `app-yes` flask app

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/yes")
def main():
    # some uploading logic
    return "Uploaded"
```

and a second folder `Desktop/FolderB` with `app-no` flask app

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/no")
def main():
    # some logic that shows available values
    return "Selected"
```

What I am basically trying is to call the `app-yes` in `app-no`, as kind of an external client.

Is there a way to do this in Flask?

Answer (score -1):

nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx;

    location /no {
        ...
        flask service no
    }

    location / {
        ...
        flask service yes
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `nginx` isn't useful for me. I will be using AWS to deploy the apps and I also want to use it for development stage